# TinyMCE value not updating

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I have tinyMCE bound to textbox inside updatepanel.
Initially I have set some value from code behind
 
After loading page in browser I update the tinymce textbox value
and When I submit the form, I am not getting updated value in the code behind,
I am getting old value only.

Help

Comment: Can you please double check that you have wrapped where you initialise the text box in !IsPostBack ?

Answer (score 3):

Added following javascript in submit buttons onclick:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```